# Cannot convert object to array and access its properties

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have the following model (object) which contains some normal fields and a nested array.

I'm trying to convert the model to a complete array, I've come across some tricks such as the following.

```
public function getMessageArray()
{
    return (array) $this->message;
}
```

But that's giving the following result

[image]

Another trick is to use the json_encode and decode as following:

```
$result= json_decode(json_encode($this->message), true);
```

But that's returning an empty array.

```
App\Mailer\Models\Message {#505
  -subject: "You bought products 3 days ago"
  -fromEmail: "no-reply@test.be"
  -fromName: "Webshop"
  -replyTo: "no-reply@test.be"
  -toEmail: "test@gmail.com"
  -toName: "Myself"
  -mergeVars: array:2 [
    "rcpt" => "test@gmail.com"
    "vars" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "name" => "fname"
        "content" => "My"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "name" => "lname"
        "content" => "Self"
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is a `print_r()` of `$this->message`

[image]

I cannot convert `$this->message` to an array to get access to all the properties. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us `print_r($this->message)`?

Comment: Added, thanks Paul

Comment: Looks like all of the object's properties are private. Does the message object not have any methods you can use to access its data?

Comment: Yes I'm using getMessage(), All properties have getters.

Comment: Aha it's working when I set all to public. I'll make a custom builder that builds a new array using the getters, that seems about right, right?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I don't know about "right", but I would say that it's at least not the intended usage. Why do you need to convert it to an array?

Comment: To send it to an API. I forgot I had to convert everything again, and for the ease of use I plan on using models. Thanks a lot for your help! If you want to may add an answer about the being private of the fields? If not I'll add one tomorrow with my solution

Comment: I see. I think your idea for a custom builder would be just right, and probably a good answer for this when you complete it.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, and instead post _actual_ text.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you obtain the dump `App\Mailer\Models\Message {#505
  -subject: "You bought products 3 days ago"
  -fromEmail: "no-reply@test.be"
  -fromName: "Webshop"
  -replyTo: "no-reply@test.be" ...
` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attributes are private, they cannot be accessed directly. `json_encode()` does not encode them.
The `PublicMaker` class below provides access to all the attributes of an object: private and public.

```
<?php
/*
* Make all the attributes of a class public
*/
class PublicMaker {

    public $matches;

    function __construct($obj) {
        // explode object attribute and values
        $print_r = print_r($obj, true);
        preg_match_all('/\[(\w*).*\] => (.*)/', $print_r, $matches);
        $this->matches = $matches;
    }

    function getArray() {
        foreach($this->matches[1] as $key=>$match) {
            $arr[$match] = $this->matches[2][$key];
        }
        return $arr;
    }

    // magic method to get any attribute of the object passed in the contructor
    function __get($attribute) {
        $match = array_search($attribute, $this->matches[1]);
        if ($match !== FALSE) {
            return $this->matches[2][$match];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

}


// test values
class Message {
    private $subject = 'You bought products 3 days ago';
    private $fromEmail = "no-reply@test.be";
    public $fromName = "Webshop";
}

// usage demonstration
$message = new Message();
$publicMessage = new PublicMaker($message);
$array = $publicMessage->getArray();
$subject = $publicMessage->subject;

echo '<pre> getArray: ';
print_r($array);

echo "\n Subject: $subject \n";

// other test values
echo "

Other test values:";
print_r((array) $message);
print_r($publicMessage->matches); // debug
echo "\n subject:   ", $publicMessage->subject; // string(30) "You bought products 3 days ago"
echo "\n fromEmail: ", $publicMessage->fromEmail;
echo "\n fromName:  ", $publicMessage->fromName;
echo "\n notExist   ", $publicMessage->notExist;
var_dump($publicMessage->notExist); // NULL
```

The regex can be tested and refined here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gje